# mean value property of a bounded function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-analysis

Let $f$ be a bounded measurable function on $R^n (n \ge 2 )$ such that it satishfies mean value property for a single radius $t >0$ i.e.
${\int_{S^{n-1}}f(x+ty) d\sigma(y)}=f(x)$ where $d\sigma(y)$ is the normalized surface measure of unit sphere. Assume further that $f$ is constant almost everywhere. Then either show that $f$ is constant or provide a counter example.

N.B.- We don't identify two bounded function if they differ by set of measure zero. In my question I have fixed a $f$.

Comment: So $f$ is constant *almost everywhere* and we're going to show that it is actually constant *everywhere*?

Comment: yes,  we need to show $f$ is constant everywhere. Thanks